# Is there a way to insert networkx graph to mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, database, networkx

I have a networkx graph that I read from a file. I would like to create a mysql table that will contain all nodes with their corresponding attributes (as columns). I know I can create a table with

```
 db_connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user='myname', passwd='mypass') 

 # Variable that exacutes Database calls with MySQL

 cursor = db_connection.cursor()

 # Create databse with MYSQL query - databasename

 cursor.execute('CREATE DATABASE inb104')

 # Select which database to use with MYSQL query - databasename

 cursor.execute('USE inb104')

 # Create database with MYSQL query - tablename & fields 

 cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE popularity (
                   PersonNumber INT,
                   Value VARCHAR(70),
                   Category VARCHAR(25),
                   PRIMARY KEY (PersonNumber, Value, Category)
                   )
               ''')
```

but I would prefer a way that will take the nodes as parameter and build the table without the need to creating the string commands (such as "create table" and "insert"). Is there such a functionality in networkx?

Answer (score 1):

At first try to read this [article](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/mysqlbook/sampler/mysqled1ch20.html)
Usually you can save graph in one table.